# Can lightning:datatable menu items be hidden for particular rows?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I know that it is possible to dynamically set menu items per each row of `lightning-datatable`, but I have a requirement to completely hide the action menu items for the particular rows which satisfy some condition.

Is this even possible to achieve using `lightning-datatable`?

Answer (score 0):

To implement this, several changes have to be made.

The first one: `class` should be added to `cellAttributes` to get the value from `cssClass` column in the data

```
    cols.push({
        'type':'action', 
        'typeAttributes':{
            'rowActions':this.getRowActions.bind(this)
        },
        'cellAttributes':{
            'class':{
                'fieldName':'cssClass'
            }
        }
    });
```

The second piece.
The data should be updated to include standard classes 'slds-hide' to hide menu or  'slds-show' to show menu

```
dataRow.cssClass = this.isOrphaned(dataRow) ? 'slds-hide' : 'slds-show';
```

Finally, the third piece.

The table may look weird because of no lines between rows where actions are hidden, to mitigate this, a fake additional column is added after the missing one to display the lines under rows which lack the menu items

```
    cols.push({
        fixedWidth: 1, hideDefaultActions: true
    });
```